# Ant script for message broker monitoring

Tags: multithreading, ant, iteration, monitoring, messagebroker

**Context**

I want to develop an automated script for broker `(IIB9/10)` resource monitoring, capturing information about broker running status, message flows deployed, jvm usage, number of threads running, etc.

The initial thought is to have a report generated using scripts and then displayed over a browser.

**Question**

Can this be entirely done using only Ant scripts (i am not sure as have not explored iterative processing in Ant in detail) or a combination of Ant and batch/shell scripts is the best bet?

I know Web user interface in `IIB10` does most of it but i want to add some features.

Comment: ANT is a build tool, not a general purpose scripting language. I would recommend looking at something like Groovy that has excellent support for ANT tasks, if you still need those features.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at message flow statistics and accounting:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac19100_.htm?lang=en

This is a feature of IIB by which it is capable of emitting resource statistics. The statistics are published to a topic in a well defined XML format. I would try solving your requirement by writing an application to read these messages and use the data in them to generate your graphs or other reports.
There is a support pack, IS03 which can give you an idea of such an application.

This will not cover everything you mentioned, for example monitoring what flows are deployed cannot be achieved like this, but it gives a comprehensive view of the load and performance of your applications:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bj10440_.htm?lang=en

And there is a resource statistics feature as well for monitoring resources used by your applications:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bj43310_.htm?lang=en

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. The above features don't meet my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

To get everything you will need a variety of tools I think. You can use Resource Stats and Accounting / Stats as suggested by Attila to get JVM and thread usage. The Broker publishes updates to a topic so you can create a simple subscriber to grab that info.

For deploy related info, stop / start state and so forth I would be looking at building simple Integration API or REST API applications to call from ant.

You can find documentation for these API's here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/be43410_.htm?lang=en

and here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.restapi.doc/index.html